headless chrome how to resolve the limitation of request concurrent(six)
I have project using chrome to convert image from url. when i benchmark, front service the cpu load increase and response slow, which cause that reach  the limitation of request concurrent. (we cannot use CDN.)
i'v listen page.EventLoadEventFired、networkIdle and sum(network.EventRequestWillBeSent) = sum(network.EventLoadingFinished) + sum(network.EventLoadingFailed)
i found that the event of network.EventRequestWillBeSent doesn't include the block requests after exceeding the limit.
How should I wait until all requests are completed before executing the task? OR How can I increase this limit quantity
i'd like execute the task(url convert image) after all requests finished.

Please share a [mcve].
